# how to split a number without losing other same characters in Java

Tags: java, regex, split

I was using Eclipse for Java and I want to split a number without losing other same characters.

For example, the input line is:
`[1142,143,2142,142]`

the output should be like that:
`1142
143
2142`

i was using `split("142|\\D+")`but the output was showing like this:
`1
143
2`

What should I do ?

Comment: why not split it with a comma. `String [] tokens = input.split(",");`

Comment: hi @UmaLakshmiKanth, because i want to split the number 142 only~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use word boundaries.

```
string.split("\\b142\\b|\\D+");
```

OR

Do replace and then split.

```
string.replaceAll("\\b142\\b|[\\[\\]]", "").split(",");
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace brackets and split:

```
String value = "[1142,143,2142,142]";

String xl = value.replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "");

String splitted[] = xl.split(",");

for (String string : splitted)          
    if (!string.matches("142"))
        System.out.println(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
,142|\\D+
```

You can split by this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/pG1kU1/30

Comment: This solution is not general enough.